# Putting curl into postman trouble

Tags: rest, http, curl, post, postman

I was converting a cURL request from the command line command to the postman format and found something odd.

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost.com/ -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

The above cURL command works in the terminal, but not in the Postman import section. I thought it wasn't a big deal, and that I would do it manually, but I can't seem to figure out what to do with the "-u testclient:testpass" portion of it.

```
-u testclient:testpass
```

Could someone please explain to me what this formatting means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As read on the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u),

```
-u, --user <user:password>
```

stands for user and password. So maybe you could select the Authorization tab, and select Basic Auth on the type. Then add the user and password.

[image]

Comment: You weren't quite right, but you helped me get there. But it would have been impossible for you to know the correct fields though.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link as well.